# Added macOS target to mixed iOS project -- why does it not find Objective-C symbols?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, build

We have a mixed Swift/Objective-C library project, created for iOS targets. This has been going fine so far.

Now, because we thought it would be nice to test (and maybe use) the library from the Swift REPL on our development Macs, we decided to add targets for macOS. Following in particular [this guide](https://theswiftdev.com/2015/03/04/how-to-make-a-universal-swift-framework/), we made sure to:

1. Copy both main and test target.
2. Adapt target OS and version.
3. Change reference to copied plist back to the project main plist.
4. Checked that all the headers are in the same places in Build Phases/Headers.
5. Changed to import of UIKit in the umbrella header (for the Objective-C parts) to Foundation.

But still, the macOS targets don't build: we get a bunch of "unresolved identifier" errors in our Swift code, pointing to symbols defined in the Objective-C code.

After giving the Objective-C submodule its own modulemap and umbrella header, the individual symbol errors go away and we get "no such module" errors on the imports.

What we *don't* see is compiler errors *in* the Objective-C code. The iOS targets still build just fine.

What are we missing here? What do we have to change to that the framework builds for macOS as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues.

1. `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS` (GUI: Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Search Paths > Import Paths) was not set on the macOS target, even though it was copied from the iOS target.

   Setting it to the same value (`$(SRCROOT)/modulefolder/`, recursive) made the build process pick up the Objective-C code.
2. Not all Objective-C files were assigned to the macOS target. Fix in the usual way.